# javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'hotels/booking/enterBookingDetails' in servlet with name 'travel'

Tags: spring, spring-3, spring-webflow-2

I've tried looking at several similar questions on StackOverflow but couldn't really understand! This is my first Spring application, so I'm sorry for a possibly duplicate question. Any help would be really appreciated.

I'm getting the following error when I navigate to enterDetails page:-

```
Exception thrown by application class 'org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render:1029'
javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'hotels/booking/enterBookingDetails' in servlet with name 'travel'
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1029)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:817)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1290)
at [internal classes]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:207)
at [internal classes]
```

Here's the controller:-

```
@RequestMapping(value = "hotels/booking", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String bookingDetails(@RequestParam Long hotelId, Model model) {     
    Booking booking = bookingService.createBooking(hotelId,"keith");
    model.addAttribute(booking);
    return "hotels/booking/enterBookingDetails";
}
```

servlet-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Configures the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Configures a handler for serving static resources by forwarding to the Servlet container's default Servlet. -->
    <default-servlet-handler />

    <!-- Maps view names to Tiles Definitions with support for partial re-rendering -->
    <beans:bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.js.ajax.AjaxUrlBasedViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.view.FlowAjaxTilesView"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Initializes the Apache Tiles CompositeView system -->
    <beans:bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
        <beans:property name="definitions">
            <beans:value>
                /WEB-INF/**/tiles.xml
            </beans:value>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Configures Spring Web FLow
    <beans:import resource="webflow.xml" /> -->

    <!-- Configures transaction management around @Transactional components -->
    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <!-- Imports the application controllers that process client requests -->
    <beans:import resource="controllers.xml" />


</beans:beans>
```

The 'FROM' Page:-

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>

<h1>${hotel.name}</h1>
<address>
    ${hotel.address}
    <br />
    ${hotel.city}, ${hotel.state}, ${hotel.zip}
    <br />
    ${hotel.country}
</address>
<form action="booking" method="get">
    <p>
        Nightly Rate:
        <spring:bind path="hotel.price">${status.value}</spring:bind>
    </p>
    <input type="hidden" name="hotelId" value="${hotel.id}" />
    <div>
        <button type="submit">Book Hotel</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

enterBookingDetails.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>

<div id="bookingForm">
    <div class="span-5">
        <h3>${booking.hotel.name}</h3>

        <address>
            ${booking.hotel.address}
            <br/>
            ${booking.hotel.city}, ${booking.hotel.state}, ${booking.hotel.zip}
            <br/>
            ${booking.hotel.country}
        </address>
        <p>
            Nightly rate: <spring:bind path="booking.hotel.price">${status.value}</spring:bind>
        </p>
    </div>
.
.
.
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:/META-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Enables use of HTTP methods PUT and DELETE -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>httpMethodFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>httpMethodFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- Secures the application 
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurity</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>targetBeanName</param-name>
            <param-value>springSecurityFilterChain</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurity</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>-->

    <!-- Handles all requests into the application -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>travel</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:/META-INF/spring/travel/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>travel</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

booking/tiles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.1//EN"
    "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_1.dtd">

<tiles-definitions>

    <definition name="enterBookingDetails" extends="standardLayout">
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/hotels/booking/enterBookingDetails.jsp"/>
    </definition>

    <definition name="reviewBooking" extends="standardLayout">
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/hotels/booking/reviewBooking.jsp" />
    </definition>

</tiles-definitions>
```

Project Explorer:-
[image]

Comment: It might be helpful if you included where your jsp file was located in the project structure.

Comment: could you post the relevant tile.xml with the definition of your view?

Comment: I'll post both of them on Monday morning! It was so stupid of me to not include them in the post!!

Comment: Just added both of them!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am new here, but I have been working on some spring MVC projects. So I hope to contribute to solving your problem.

I would change your controller to be able to work with the ModelAndView object, so you can do the following:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "hotels/booking", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView bookingDetails(@RequestParameter Long hotelId) {  

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("enterBookingDetails");
    Booking booking = bookingService.createBooking(hotelId,"keith");
    model.addObject("booking", booking);
    return model;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response!
I just tried this but unfortunately I'm still getting the exact same error!

Comment: sorry, I saw that I made a mistake in my code, so I changed it. I also noticed that you are calling the view with "hotels/booking/enterBookingDetails", however I think maybe you only need to call the name, since you are using the tiles in wich you have already declared the path.

Comment: The problem was infact calling the view with "hotels/booking/enterBookingDetails" instead of just "enterBookingDetails". Did that just now and it started working! May be you would want to update that in the original answer and I'll accept it as the answer!
Thanks a lot man!

Comment: Great! I have updated the answer, happy to have helped!